# Python - copying the index of a sorted list

Tags: python

I have an array of names and an array of votes, the arrays are matching index's. If I sort the votes in descending order then how do I sort the names the same way?

Comment: Can't you use dictionary instead of lists? Then use sorted function with values method.

Comment: `sorted(zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: BTW, keeping two lists in parallel is not fun. I suggest uniting them in some way, eg create a list of tuples. Some of the answers in the linked question show how to do that using `zip` as part of their sorting procedure.

Comment: @jspcal, it won't work, if votes are in `list2`

Comment: No @akshat, it is the answer.